# neo4j Out of Memory error when using python

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm getting the following out of memory error when running neo4j queries in Python. I'm using `neo4j 4.1.0 desktop`.

```
neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.alpha.shortestPath.deltaStepping.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space}
```

I've followed the instructions to change the memory available: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/ and assigned 12GB to the relevant parameters in the conf file:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=12g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=12g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=12g
```

My database has 63,000 nodes and 57,000 relationships

My python code looks like this and is called in a loop, with the `id` value changing each time:

```
neo4j_session = neo4j_driver.session()
results_data = neo4j_session.run("MATCH (start:Person {id: 21) \
        CALL gds.alpha.shortestPath.deltaStepping.stream({ \
            nodeQuery:'MATCH(n:Person) RETURN id(n) AS id', \
            relationshipQuery:'MATCH (p1:Person {id: 21})-[p1Knows:KNOWS]->(p1s)-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF*..10]-(p2s)<-[p2Knows:KNOWS]-(p2:Person) WHERE p1.id <> p2.id and p1Knows.self_rating <> 0 and p1Knows.self_rating < p2Knows.self_rating with p1, p2, reduce(cost = 0, x IN r | cost + coalesce(x.distance, 0)) as cost  RETURN id(p1) AS source, id(p2) AS target, cost AS weight', \
            startNode: start, \
            relationshipWeightProperty: 'weight', \
            delta: 3.0, \
            writeProperty: 'sssp' \
        }) \
        YIELD nodeId, distance \
        where gds.util.isFinite(distance) \
        with nodeId, gds.util.asNode(nodeId) as n, distance \
        RETURN n.name AS Name, distance AS Cost \
        ORDER BY Cost".format(person_id)).data()

neo4j_session.close()
```

The error doesn't occur on the same id each time, so I'm wondering if I'm not using the python driver correctly and not clearing something up?

If not, do I really need 12GB of memory to query the graph?

Answer (score 1):

I always call **write_transaction** then use **run** to execute the query works fine for me, I have a much larger database than yours no errors.
The issue might be that you are opening and closing session in the for loop.

```
 def data(tx):
     # run your for loop here
     tx.run(" RUN YOUR QUERY ")

 with driver.session() as session:
    session.write_transaction(data)
 driver.close()
```

Comment: thanks for that. unfortunately still got the same error :( but it's good to know about `write_transaction`

Comment: have you tried running the cypher query on neo4j directly?

Comment: yes. individually the queries are fine. It's when they're put together in a loop that it falls over.

Comment: try putting timeout between the queries